# Why does running the CoffeeScript compiler multiple times produce different output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm attempting to compile the very simple coffee script:

```coffee
n = 4;
```

Using the code

```js
require('coffee-script').compile(str);
```

I do this multiple times in my solution, without caching the results.  The first time I do this, I get:

```js
(function() {
    var n;
    n = 4;
}).call(this);
```

but if I then call it again, I get:

```
n = 4;
```

Why don't I get the wrapper function the second time round, and how can I make it give the same results every time.

Comment: Can't reproduce, I get the same (wrapped) code everytime. Have you tried `coffee.compile(str, { bare: false })`? Post your code.

Comment: @Ricardo That fixed it, surprising behaviour since before I had undefined for options.bare.  Still, glad it's sorted.  If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce, I get the same (wrapped) code everytime.

Use `coffee.compile(str, { bare: false })` to enforce the closure wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might happen (i.e. different outputs) due to scope issues.

Normally you need only one `var` statement for variable. And it seems to be that during the first call all needed declarations were created and second call just reuses them.

I believe it might happen due to fact that the same `require('coffee-script')` instance is used.

Comment: OK, is there a way to disable the cache of 'coffee-script' so I require it fresh each time then?

Also, the `var` statements are still needed because the code for the first bit get's wrapped in a self calling function, so the second call to assign `n` will assign it to the `global` object.

Answer (score 0):

Compile just didn't work for some reason the second time around. CoffeeScript code is always wrapped in a function.

Comment: So is the suggestion that I fire up a second process?  Or is there another way to access the API?